# How to pass an array as argument (in Python) when solving ODE by odeint function

Tags: python, ode

My ODE is given as Mx''+Lx'+f(x)=0 where f(x) is a polynomial function. Please look at my FULL CODE where I defined the differential equation in a function namely 'diff'. Then I use 'odeint' which calls 'diff' along with the necessary arguments to solve the differential equaion.

Now I consider f(x)=ax. Here I have to pass three parameters in total (M,L,a) as the argument to the 'diff' function. As a matter of fact the code works if I write: (see full code)

```
 sol = odeint(diff, y0, t, args=(M,L, a))
```

But when f(x) is a polynomial up to  10 power of 'x', then the parameter list becomes too long. Therefore I want to put all the parameters in an array and then pass that array as argument. I tried in this way:

```
def diff(y, t, inertia):
    M=inertia[0]
    L=inertia[1]
    a=inertia[2]

    x,v = y
    dydt = [v, (-L*v - a*x)/M]
    return dydt

M=5
L = 0.5
a = 5.0
Inertia=(M,L,a)

sol = odeint(diff, y0, t, args=Inertia)
```

But this approach doen't work. It says 'TypeError: diff() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given'.

How can I can I make this approach work, or how to send a list of parameters as argument?

**Full Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def diff(y, t, M, L, a):   
    x,v = y
    dydt = [v, (-L*v - a*x)/M]
    return dydt

M=5
L = 0.5
a = 5.0

#Inertia=(M,L,a)
#But I cant pass the 'Inertia' as an argument 


y0 = [- 0.1, 0.0]
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
sol = odeint(diff, y0, t, args=(M,L, a))



plt.plot(t, sol[:, 0], 'b', label='x(t)')
plt.plot(t, sol[:, 1], 'g', label='v(t)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Inertia` in this case is a tuple. `odeint` expects a tuple of arguments as its `args` parameter, so `Inertia` gets unpacked and the arguments to diff become `y0, t, M, L, a`. To circumvent this, you should pack `Inertia` in another tuple to make `Inertia` a single argument, like so:

```
sol = odeint(diff, y0, t, args=(Inertia,))
```

Note the `,` after `Inertia`. this makes it a tuple (`(a) == a`, `(a,) == tuple(a)`)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach doesn't work because you have assigned `inertia` as a tuple instead of an array. Correct is `inertia=[a,b,c]`.
As arguments are passed to functions as well, your "array" gets appended to the other argumenty when passing it to a function an so this function receives 5 arguments.